# Is an example specified in "discrete mathematics with applications" a contradiction?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Now I'm back in the world of math and have already encountered with such a confusion.
Let's look to this task (You'll need to pay attention to point "c").

[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsGT0.png)

So one of the constraicts of a function definition is that

> for every $x$ in set $A$ and $z$ in set $B$, if $(x, z)$ in $F$ (where $F$ is a
> function) and $(x, z)$ in $F$, then $y = z$

Here is an explanation why the relation from point "c" is a function

> $T$ is a function: Each element in $\{2, 4, 6\}$ is related to some element
> in $\{1, 3, 5\}$ and no element in $\{2, 4, 6\}$ is related to more than one
> element in $\{1, 3, 5\}$. When these properties are stated in terms of the
> arrow diagram, they become (1) there is an arrow coming out of each
> element of the domain, and (2) no element of the domain has more than
> one arrow coming out of it. So you can write $T (2) = 5, T (4) = 1$, and
> $T (6) = 1$.

Isn't the decision contradictory to the very definition of a function?
I would appreciate an explanation, thanks.

Comment: In short, no this is not a contradiction. Please check the first quote you use as currently it doesn't make sense. In general a function can have multiple elements map to the same value, for example take $x^2$. Hopefully that helps, if not let me know.

Comment: "Isn't the decision contradictory to the very definition of a function?" What makes you say that?

Comment: On an unrelated note, I don't really think that analysis fits as a tag for this question, although I guess that is a bit subjective and if you are new to maths it is an easy mistake.

Comment: Consider the sets $X = \{a,b\}$ and $Y= \{1,2\}$. $F = \{(a,1),(b,1)\}$ is a function but $R=\{(a,1),(a,2)\}$ is not. Consider what it means for a function to be invertible in this context.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no contradiction, but your definition of a function is wrong.

A function $f\subseteq A\times B$ is a relation such that

- for every $a\in A$ there is some $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$, and
- for every $a\in A$ and $b,b'\in B$, if $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,b')\in f$, then $b=b'$.

In words the first point of the definition states that every element in the domain $A$ of $f$ has a function value, and the second point states that no element is related to multiple values. One can combine this to say that every element in the domain is related to a **unique** function value.

Comment: Thanks, I undestood where I was wrong!